# Find general and unique solution of a recurrence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

My solution:
since order $2$, then
$r^2 - 5r + 6 = 0$.  Then 
$(r - 2 ) (r - 3) = 0$, so
$r_1 = 2$  and $r_2 = 3$.

Is it correct?
If it's correct, then how can I find the general and unique solution?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format math on this site.

Comment: @almagest help please

Comment: $a_n=C\cdot2^n+D\cdot3^n;$ you could solve for $C$ and $D$ since you know $a_1$ and $a_2$

Comment: @J. W. Tanner  to make sure that a'm right tell me the value of C and D

Answer (score 0):

Let $A(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nz^n$ be the generating function of $\{a_n\}$. Multiplying both sides of the recurrence by $z^n$ and summing over $n=3$ to infinity, we have
$$
\sum_{n=3}^\infty a_nz^n = 5\sum_{n=3}^\infty a_{n-1}z^n -6\sum_{n=3}^\infty a_{n-2}z^n.
$$
Some algebraic manipulation yields
$$
A(z) -a_1z -a_2z^2 = 5z(A(z)-a_1z) - 6z^2A(z).
$$
Solving for $A(z)$, we have
$$
A(z) = \frac{15 z^2-2 z}{(1-3z)(1-2z)}.
$$
Partial fraction decomposition yields
$$
A(z) = \frac{3}{1-3z}-\frac{11}{2 (1-2z)}+\frac{5}{2}
$$
Expanding $A(z)$ as a series, we have
\begin{align}
A(z) &= 3\sum_{n=1}^\infty 3^nz^n - \frac{11}2\sum_{n=1}^\infty  2^nz^n + \frac52\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty (3^{n+1}-11\cdot 2^{n-1})z^n + \frac52,
\end{align}
so $a_n = 3^{n+1}-11\cdot 2^{n-1}$, $n\geqslant 1$.

Comment: an = -11/2 (2)^n + 3(3)^n can be written in this way

Answer (score 0):

You got $r_1=2$ and $r_2=3$.

The general solution is $a_n=C\cdot2^n+D\cdot3^n$.

The particular solution for $a_1=-2$ and $a_2=5$ has $C=\dfrac{-11}2$ and $D=3$;

i.e., $a_n=-11\cdot2^{n-1}+3^{n+1}$.

Comment: an = -11/2 (2)^n + 3(3)^n    can be written in this way. a'm I right?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: I have non homogeneous recurrence relation question can I drop the question if you answer for me

Comment: Find the general solution of the following recurrence relation:  an - 11an-1 + 30an-2 = n^2(5^n)

Comment: @endi:  you should post that as a separate question and show some effort

Comment: yes but I limited please answer in here and thank you I need the answer for know

Comment: please J. W. Tanner